# I'm getting this error when I tried to run main.dart on my physical android device. Please can anybody help me to fix this error

Tags: flutter, android-studio, gradle

When I execute `flutter run` command then:

```
E:\Flutter_Projects\test_project_2\android>flutter run     
Changing current working directory to: E:\Flutter_Projects\test_project_2
Launching lib\main.dart on ART L28 in debug mode...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timeout of 120000 reached waiting for exclusive access to file: C:\Users\senit\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-7.4-all\aadb4xli5jkdsnukm30eibyiu\gradle-7.4-all.zip
        at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:61)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                            121.2s
```

Answer (score 1):

try to run `./gradlew clean` and `./gradlew build` in your project's android directory.